# How to Share Models Between WP7 and Azure Projects

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, azure

I have a WP7 project, which will invoke a REST web service in Azure (MVC4 WebApi).

My WP7 project has models that it serializes to JSON and then sends to the web service.

The web service deserializes the data sent from WP7 and instantiates the models again before saving them to Azure Table Storage.

How can I share the Model classes between the projects? Right now I'm just copying the cs files over, and I have to update both sets if I make a change to the models. I was hoping a simple class library project would be able to be referenced from both projects, but WP7 couldn't handle that.

What should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many solutions for this issue:

- You could use a T4 template to read the entity and generate a class your WP7 project that only contains the properties of the object without reference to the Table Storage specifics (like TableStorageEntity): http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2009/03/11/code-generation-with-t4-an-entities-to-dto-example.aspx
- You could split your entity over 2 files, one with the TableStorage specifics like TableStorageEntity and one file containing only the properties of the entity (use partial classes for this). Then you can add the file containing only the properties in your WP7 project [as a link](http://visualstudiohacks.com/options/add-an-existing-file-to-a-project-without-copying-it/).
- Create a DTO (or whatever you call it) class manually and use something like AutoMapper to map between the DTO and the TableStorage entity. Store the DTO in a [portable library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx) so it can be used by every kind of project. In my opinion this is the best solution since you don't want to completely expose your entities to "the outside world". An example would be a list of users. You wouldn't want to return all fields including password, hash... and other sensitive info. It would be better to have a separate class that only contains the info you want to expose externally.

Comment: I think you're being a bit overcomplex.  He didn't say his models are generated by anything/one other than himself (i.e., EF models).  +1 for defining the models in a portable library assembly.

Comment: Hmm I don't really understand your comment. His problem is that he needs to update both sets if he wants to change the model. But unless he uses T4 templates or splits files over partial classes, he'll always have to do this since with TableStorage, your entities inherit from TableStorageEntity, and this class isn't available on WP7.

Comment: Thanks guys - I'll check into this and get back here when I've done so!

Comment: @SandrinoDiMattia: Simplest solution is to define your models in a third assembly that is a portable class library.  Why do anything else?  Well, if you're using EF4 or other ORM frameworks, then you have to do something else.  The point of my comment is that *he didn't say he's using an ORM*.  I don't know if he is or not.  If not, go the simplest route first before thinking about T4 templates, etc.

Comment: He said he's using TableStorage.

Comment: Seems like that's going to work! If I decorate my models with the [DataServiceKey("PartitionKey", "RowKey")] attribute and reference System.Data.Services.Client in my portable project, then I don't need to reference the WindowsAzure assembly that has the TableServiceEntity class that you usually inherit from in order to  use the Table Service. This means that I don't need to break my classes up - they should be able to live in both the Azure and the WP7 projects without modification (fingers crossed).